# Display PDF in new Tab

Tags: html, pdf

I linked a pdf like that:

```
<a href="mypdf.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>
```

and would like it to open/display in a new Tab. Instead, a new Tab is opened and the pdf is downloaded.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML you have is fine for the result you desire.

You also need to ensure:

- The HTTP response containing the PDF does **not** include `Content-Disposition: attachment`
- The browser supports inline display of PDFs (and that support is not disabled or overridden).